Understanding a formula in Rosenblatt's perceptron paper
I want to be an AI researcher and realized that I've never really read an AI paper (or any academic paper for that matter) all the way through, and seriously tried to understand the content. Before getting to newer stuff, I decided to try and read Frank Rosenblatt's paper introducing the perceptron.
I've gotten stuck trying to understand a particular formula in the paper, giving the "expected proportion of A-units [basically hidden layer neurons] activated by a stimulus of a given size"
The formula given (pages 7-8 in the provided link) is
$P_a = \sum\limits_{e = \theta}^x \sum\limits_{i = \theta}^{\min(y, e-\theta)}P(e, i)$
where
$P(e, i) = {x \choose e}R^e(1 - R)^{x - e} {y \choose i}R^i(1 - R)^{y - i}$
and
$P_a$ = expected proportion of hidden layer neurons activated by the stimulus
$R$ = the proportion of "S-points" (input layer neurons) activated by the stimulus
$x$ = number of excitatory connections to each hidden layer neuron (connections with weight +1)
$y$ = number of inhibitory connections to each hidden layer neuron (connections with weight -1)
$\theta$ = threshold of the hidden layer neurons. The sum of the excitatory and inhibitory signals must be greater than or equal to $\theta$ for the neuron to fire.
I think I understand the formula for $P(e, i)$. As far as I know, it gives the proportion of hidden layer neurons which receive $e$ excitatory stimuli and $i$ inhibitory stimuli, and nothing about that formula really bothers me.
However, I don't get the formula for $P_a$. It seems to me that for a neuron to fire, it needs to have at least $\theta$ more excitatory impulses than inhibitory ones, right? Therefore for any given $e$, shouldn't $i$ range from 0 to $e - \theta$, instead of $\theta$ to $e - \theta$. Where am I going wrong here?
